# Pandas/Numpy Map Column of column names to values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, transformation

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column with the name of a column from another pandas dataframe. So for example:

```
a
var1
var3
var2
...
```

Then another dataframe that looks like this:

```
var1   var2   var3   ...
5      8      9      ...
9      3      2      ...
...
```

The result I would want is a numpy array where the rows correspond to the rows of the first, and the columns refer to the time series from the second based on the column name in the first.

In this example here I'd expect the result to be:

```
5  9  ...
9  2  ...
8  3  ...
...
```

I know I can do .loc like this:

```
a.loc[a == "var1","new_col"] = df2["var1"]
b.loc[a == "var2","new_col"] = df2["var2"]
b.loc[a == "var3","new_col"] = df2["var3"]
...
```

or something like that. I know that out of the box wouldn't work due to needing to expand but even if it did or if an np.where was able to work this way I want to avoid that because there are a LOT of variables here and I'm trying to see if I can do a map-style approach to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.T.to_numpy()` ? does that work?

Comment: Which df? I have two of them.

Comment: Just your DF with your data.  You can reindex that data with your list from the first df.  @not_speshal has a solution close to what I would suggests.

Comment: Is it possible to have repetition on column `a` on the first `df`?

Comment: Yes there is a ton of repetition in column a

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `df1` contains the order of the rows and `df2` is the data, you can do:

```
>>> df2[df1["a"].tolist()].T
      0  1
var1  5  9
var3  9  2
var2  8  3
```

Comment: Agreed. Just based it off OP's first statement that `df1` is constructed using `df2`'s column names

Comment: @ScottBoston according to the last comment as we do have repetition this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas-dataframe-t) + [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex):

```
df3 = df2.T.reindex(df1['a'])
```

`df3`:

```
      0  1
a         
var1  5  9
var3  9  2
var2  8  3
```

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['var1', 'var3', 'var2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [5, 9], 'var2': [8, 3], 'var3': [9, 2]})

df3 = df2.T.reindex(df1['a'])

print(df3)
```

---

With repetitions:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['var1', 'var3', 'var2', 'var3', 'var1']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [5, 9], 'var2': [8, 3], 'var3': [9, 2]})

df3 = df2.T.reindex(df1['a'])

print(df3)
```

`df3`:

```
      0  1
a         
var1  5  9
var3  9  2
var2  8  3
var3  9  2
var1  5  9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['var1','var3','var2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var1':[5,9],'var2':[8,3],'var3':[9,2]})

new_df = df2[df1['a']].T
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
        0   1
var1    5   9
var3    9   2
var2    8   3
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment you can have repetitons in columns `a` on your first dataframe. A possible approach could be the following:

## Sample Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["var1", "var3", "var2", "var1"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3),
                   columns=["var1", "var2", "var3"])
```

## Extract dictionary from `df2`

```py
diz = {}
for col in df2.columns:
    diz[col] = df2[col].values
```

## Use Map and transform to array

```py
mat = np.array(df1["a"].map(diz).tolist())
```